# How to upgrade from 13.10 beta to stable release?

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I installed 13.10 when it was either in beta/alpha, and now would like to upgrade to the official release. How should I go about this? Should I just make a new install disk and use that? Any help is much appreciated.